# Whats the best way to introduce decrypting and showing passwords in delphi

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, browser, hash, msn-messenger

A few weeks ago I lost my passwords for msn and more importent my company email, which change every 30 days or something, they are annoying because of there lengh and a I dont like writting them down.
Anyhow I downloaded a so called password recovery tool and it worked well, but then spammed me for days with ads.
My question is, how can I go about making a tool like this in delphi.
There are soooo many programs that do this, well I want my own that I can trust.
I have 8 msn accounts yes 8 and each one is for each company we deal with, its very confusing..   I need....

1. locates all usernames
2. decrpts passes to show with matching names
3. shows both in memo1 and memo2

now the code I need must start with a function, must store in strings, and must end result should be, showmessage(functionname);

You see this has happened a few times so If I can make a tool to auto locate and remember usernames and passes I use in the webrowser it would be much better.
I normally reset the web browser of usernames and passes every 10 days, well the script does that.

Comment: I think what you actually need is a password keeper.

Comment: I need to decrypt my passwords stored on my computer and store them with the usernames, if I require one I can just load my delphi application up and look for the stored pass with matching email.

it dont even have to match up, even just all the names and all the passwords shown in memo1 and memo2.
that would do, but if they can be matched even better and would save me more time.
I dont want to enter the info manually each time they change to much hard work, i dont need a keeper.

Comment: Do you use the browser's auto-save feature to remember the passwords?  Is this for IE, FireFox, or both?

Comment: Firefox will simply display all the stored passwords if you ask it to. Doesn't Internet Explorer have a similar feature? If not, have you considered switching?

Comment: As Adrian suggests, instead of reinventing the wheel, take a look at a password manager like Keepass (open source / free) - http://keepass.info/

Comment: +1 for KeePass. It's open source, and works very reliably.

Comment: hi everyone and thanks, so after reading all the info which is the best way forward, yes I store my passwords both on firefox and IE, I understand if I do not store the passwords there is no way of recovery.
I want to program using delphi a way to retrieve the passwords stored by the browers into memos.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Internet Explorer stores passwords in [Protected Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432403.aspx). To read from there, use the [`PStoreCreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432404.aspx) function to get an `IPStore` interface.

Code Project has a [demonstration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/HirPStorage.aspx) of how to use that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that in latest CodeGear RAD Studio version are very wide Indy, IW Component package included. The help also is improved, so there is possible to even find some WinAPI included functions.

Some time ago I had to deal with very simple and very unhandy internet rss / file downlaoding solution requiring dynamic dll loadings and there the beast and the easyies one I had to work with was TdFTP class functions, which integrates password and login interface using settable SSL/TSL password encriptions. Pretty basic, but imho effective approach to use as password handler, even if there are no real file transferring requiered.

Unfourtinately I dodnt remember excat password storaging method or file or interfac

Hope this was useful answer, even if I did not provide detailed information.

YOU MAY WANT TO TAKE A LOOK AT: [CSC](http://www.filetransit.com/view.php?id=34536)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to use GMail with multiple registered email addresses

Comment: I know Google has lots of services, but I'm pretty sure that recovering passwords stored by your Web browser isn't one of them.

Comment: That wasnt my point I though he was creating a new msn email address for each customer I felt instead he could use one GMail account for all his mail and send it out using differnt addresses, but now that I read the question again I see it is msn messenger accounts he's talking about so I guess the -1 is justified :)